# LINQ to Entities with Multiple databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

I need to do an Insert on a table in a different database (same engine), then insert "locally", then for each inserted i have to do a loop to insert in a child table.

The scenario is this: `Person`, `Contract`, `PayOrder` (local), `PayOrder` (db2), `Contracts_PayOrder`. (The code itself isn't in english, but I added comments)

For each `contract` that a `person` have, I need to create ONE `PayOrder` (in the 2 different databases) with a value that is the sum of all contracts, Then again, for each contract I have to make an insert on `Contracts_PayOrder`

I created 2 different .edmx for that. This is what i'm getting when trying to `SaveChanges` on the LocalDB: (Read the comments on the code)

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed
>   because there are other threads running in the session.

This is my attempt:

```
using (RegistroContratoEntities dbs = new RegistroContratoEntities())
{
    //Get list of active PERSONS
    IQueryable<Credor> credorList = dbs.Credores.Where(c => c.Status == true);

    foreach (Credor credor in credorList)
    {
        //Keep the payOrder Id
        decimal? renavamBoletoId = null;

        //Get list of contracts for that person

        IQueryable<Contrato> contratosCredor = dbs.Contratos
            .Where(c => c.Credor_Id == credor.Id &&
                   c.DataRegistro.Value.Month == pMesReferencia &&
                   c.Status == true);

        if (contratosCredor.Count() > 0)
        {
            // Gets the total cost of the PayOrder
            decimal valorBoleto = contratosCredor.Count() * 11;

            //
            // Creates the PayOrder (One for each person) on the external db
            //

            using (RenavamEntities dbren = new RenavamEntities())
            {
                BoletoRenavam boletoREN = new BoletoRenavam();

                boletoREN.Arquivo = null;
                boletoREN.BoletoSituacao_Id = CodBoletoSituacao.Ativo;
                boletoREN.ConvenioBoleto_Id = CodBoletoConvenio.Padrao;
                boletoREN.Emissao = DateTime.Now;
                boletoREN.LogDataAlteracao = DateTime.Now;
                boletoREN.LogUsuario = "RegistroContratos";
                boletoREN.LogVersaoRegistro = 1;
                boletoREN.Pagamento = null;
                boletoREN.PagamentoValor = null;
                boletoREN.Processamento = null;
                boletoREN.Status = "S";
                boletoREN.ParcelaValor = valorBoleto;
                boletoREN.Vencimento = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);

                dbren.AddToBoleto(boletoREN);
                dbren.SaveChanges();

                renavamBoletoId = boletoREN.Id;
            }

            //
            // The PayOrder on the "main"" db
            //
            Boleto boletoREG = new Boleto();

            boletoREG.NumeroBoletoRenavam = renavamBoletoId;
            boletoREG.ArquivoRetorno = null;
            boletoREG.BoletoConvenio_Id = CodBoletoConvenio.Padrao;
            boletoREG.BoletoSituacao_Id = CodBoletoSituacao.Ativo;
            boletoREG.Credor_Id = credor.Id;
            boletoREG.Emissao = DateTime.Now;
            boletoREG.LogAlteracao = DateTime.Now;
            boletoREG.LogUsuario = pUsuario;
            boletoREG.LogVersao = 1;
            boletoREG.NumeroBoletoRenavam = null;
            boletoREG.Pagamento = null;
            boletoREG.PagamentoValor = null;
            boletoREG.Processamento = null;
            boletoREG.Status = true;
            boletoREG.Valor = valorBoleto;
            boletoREG.Vencimento = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);

            dbs.AddToBoletos(boletoREG);
            dbs.SaveChanges();

            //
            // Then, for each contract, inserts a row in a child table that
            // will relate all contracts with it's PayOrders

            foreach (Contrato contrato in contratosCredor)
            {
                BoletoTaxaContrato boletoContrato = new BoletoTaxaContrato();

                boletoContrato.Boleto = boletoREG;
                boletoContrato.Contrato = contrato;
                boletoContrato.Data = DateTime.Now;
                boletoContrato.LogAlteracao = DateTime.Now;
                boletoContrato.LogUsuario = pUsuario;
                boletoContrato.LogVersao = 1;
                boletoContrato.Quantidade = 1;
                boletoContrato.Taxa_Id = CodBoletoTaxa.RegistroContrato;

                dbs.AddToBoletoTaxaContratos(boletoContrato);
                dbs.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close first context before opening new one.

I know that you need some data from another context but you can load it before (cast it to list|entity for example to execute your query before first context will be closed).